# How To Solve Laravel and MySql Error Called SQLSTATE[23000]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to create a Registration form. So, I have created a `RegShortController.php` file and after I have created view file called `RegShort.blade.php`. In `RegShortController.php` file , I have used a function called insert. But , When I run the Web Site , I got this error -

> "`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name'
>   cannot be null (SQL: insert into`academic`(`name`,`username`,`pw`)
>   values (, , ))`"

So , How to Fix this ??

[image]

> Here is the RegShort.blade.php file

Unfortunately , I have removed name attributes in username and password when I edit this Thread. Now , I fixed it.

```
<form action="{{ route('RegShort') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{{ csrf_field() }}

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name : *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username : *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password : *</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

> Here is the RegShortController.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class RegShortController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('RegShort');
    }

    function insert(Request $req)
    {

        $name = $req->input('name');
        $username = $req->input('username');
        $password = $req->input('password');

        $data = array("name"=>$name,'username'=>$username,"pw"=>$password);

        DB::table('academic')->insert($data);

    }

}
```

> Here is the Route that I have created.

```
Route::any('/RegShort', 'RegShortController@insert')->name('RegShort');
```

Comment: assign a value to the name column or remove the constrains  from the  table

Comment: why don't you use `Model`..?

Comment: You don't have a `name` attribute one the `username` input or the `password` input, this will mean the data for those inputs won't be in the request anyway.

Comment: Does the name input have a value when you submit the form?

Comment: @scaisEdge - It didn't work..

Comment: @ZaheerAttar - Still I'm new to Laravel.. So, I'm studying these things.. How can use Model with this Task ??

Comment: @RossWilson - Unfortunately , I have removed name attributes in username and password when I edit this Thread. Now , I fixed it.

Comment: @RossWilson - When I use Route::any('/RegShort', 'RegShortController@index')->name('RegShort'); , I can go into the Form. But, when I use Route::any('/RegShort', 'RegShortController@insert')->name('RegShort'); , I can't go even into the Form. It shows me that Error.

Comment: @KistlakRajapaksha This is best tutorial, learn from here.. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

Comment: @ZaheerAttar - Thank U Very Much Bro !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` field must be non empty, so u should validate data before inserting it (server side validation):

```
function insert(Request $req)
{

    $this->validate($req, [
       'name' => 'required'
    ]);

    $name = $req->input('name');
    $username = $req->input('username');
    $password = $req->input('password');

    $data = array("name"=>$name,'username'=>$username,"pw"=>$password);

    DB::table('academic')->insert($data);

}
```

BTW would be nice to validate data by javascript as well before sending data to server (client side validation).

Edit ur HTML, uve missed name attributes for ur inputs:

```
<form action="{{ route('RegShort') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{{ csrf_field() }}

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name : *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username : *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password : *</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Also change ur routes:

```
Route::get('/RegShort', 'RegShortController@index')->name('RegShort');
Route::post('/RegShort', 'RegShortController@insert');
```

Comment: If his `name` field is really needed, he can also add the `required` attribute to it.

Comment: @ЛевМакаренко - Now it's saying " The localhost page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times. ".. So , How to Fix this ??

Comment: @ЛевМакаренко - Yeah , It's 100% Perfectly Worked !! Thank U Very Much Bro !! But , when I use PUT methods , it shows me this error - MethodNotAllowedHttpException. So , I used POST method and It worked..

Comment: Thats because {{ method_field('PUT') }} was missed in blade template file

Comment: @ЛевМакаренко - What is the difference between PUT and POST ??

Comment: Due to RESTful way we must use POST for insert and PATCH/PUT methods for update. So its ok to use POST method for insert data in this example.

Comment: @ЛевМакаренко - Again , Thank U Very Much Bro !!

Comment: @ЛевМакаренко - I need your held here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529600/how-to-solve-this-data-update-error-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are unable to get data from the $req object. Be sure to check your data before inserting into the table.

Comment: How can I do it ??

Answer (score 1):

you dont have name attribute for username and password

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name : *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username : *</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password : *</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
  </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately , I have removed name attributes in username and password when I edit this Thread. Now , I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update html:

**You are messing:** **name** attribute here

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required>
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
```

**Code:**

```
<form action="{{ route('RegShort') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{{ csrf_field() }}

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name : *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username : *</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password : *</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately , I have removed name attributes in username and password when I edit this Thread. Now , I fixed it. 
Any , help for that name null error ??