# How To Solve This Data Update Error In Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to Update a Registration Form data. So , at first I have created a Table for the show data. In this table , I have included an ViewForUpdate button and I have passed the Id. When I click that ViewForUpdate button , it shows unique data correctly in an another page. After I inputted new data and when I click update button , it shows this error -

> ```
> MethodNotAllowedHttpException
> ```

So , How to fix this ??

> Here is the RegViewUpdate.blade.php file

```
<html>
<head>

<body>

<form action="edit{{$users[0]->id}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{{ method_field('PUT') }}
{{ csrf_field() }}

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name : *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$users[0]->name}}" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username : *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{$users[0]->username}}" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password : *</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{$users[0]->pw}}" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Upload Profile Picture :</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="file_img" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">If U Want , U Can Skip Upload A Profile Picture</small>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Update">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the RegViewController.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class RegViewController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('RegView');
    }

    public function show($id) {
        $users = DB::select('select * from academic where id = ?',[$id]);
        return view('RegViewUpdate',['users'=>$users]);
    }

    public function edit(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $name = $request->input('name');

        DB::update('update academic set name = ? where id = ?',[$name,$id]);
        echo "Record updated successfully.<br/>";

    }

}
```

> Here is the Routes that I have created.

```
Route::get('edit/{id}','RegViewController@show');
Route::post('edit{id}','RegViewController@edit');
```

> `academic` table Structure.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

*RegViewUpdate.blade.php*

```
<html>
<head>

<body>

<form action="edit/{{$users[0]->id}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{{ method_field('PUT') }}
{{ csrf_field() }}

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name : *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$users[0]->name}}" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username : *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{$users[0]->username}}" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password : *</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{$users[0]->pw}}" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Upload Profile Picture :</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="file_img" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">If U Want , U Can Skip Upload A Profile Picture</small>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Update">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

*RegViewController.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class RegViewController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('RegView');
    }

    public function show($id) {
        $users = DB::select('select * from academic where id = ?',[$id]);
        return view('RegViewUpdate',['users'=>$users]);
    }

    public function edit(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $name = $request->input('name');
        try {
             DB::table('academic')
                  ->where('id', $id)
                  ->update(['name' => $name]);
             echo "Record updated successfully.<br/>";
        }  catch (\Exception $ex) {
             dd($ex);
        }
    }

}
```

*Routes:*

```
Route::get('edit/{id}','RegViewController@show');
Route::put('edit/{id}','RegViewController@edit');
```

Comment: It doesn't work with action="edit/{{ $users[0]->id }}" and I removed the slash. And now it's working. Shows me a successful message. But , when I check Database , it shows me old data which had before the update. It means still doesn't update my data. How to Fix this ??

Comment: It updates only name field due to original code, are u sure name fields are the same ?

Comment: Yes , name field is same even after it showed the successful message.

Comment: Now I can Update name field.. But , Username and password didn't update. i used this query - update(['name' => $name],['username' => $username],['pw' => $password]);

Comment: Just add additional fields for update into array parameter for ->update() method: update(['name' => $name, 'username' => $username, 'pw' => $password]);

Comment: Seriously , you are a Genius.. Thank U Very Much Bro !! :D

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will want to remove the following line:

```
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

The reason is that your Route is set up to use the POST method, so the PUT Route is not defined. Alternately, you could change it to specify the PUT method (which is redundant, because your  specifies that already), or use the {{ Form::open() }} tag with the appropriate Route.

Answer (score 1):

it should be PUT method on route

**Form action should be**  -

/edit/{{$users[0]->id}}

**and route should be -**

Route::put('/edit/{id}','RegViewController@edit');

Because you are using PUT method to send id.

Comment: Now it shows me thie error - Not Found /

The requested URL /edit/38 was not found on this server. But , Data still in Database.

Comment: It doesn't work with one slash and I removed the slash. And now it's working. Shows me a successful message. But , when I check Database , it shows me old data which had before the update. It means still doesn't update my data. How to Fix this ??

Answer (score 1):

i have found two issues with your code

- in your view file
- in your route

1) replace your form tag in your view file as below

```
{!! 
 Form::open(
               ['method' => 'PUT',
                'route' => ['update','id of data to update']
             ])
!!}

// place your form content here

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

2) change your route as below

Route::PUT('update/{id}','controller_name@update_method_name');

- replace controller_name = Your Controller Name
- replace update_method_name = Your Method name for update

Comment: What is this $task and update ?? Should I replace with something ??

Comment: remove the $task from the {!! Form::open() !!} and update is name of route so no need to change it.